# Nomenclature or alternatives

Tags: nouns

Suppose I invent a phrase to describe a particular thing, such as *"the three-particle paradigm"*, which is a new paradigm that I have developed to think about a certain field within particle physics.

I'm looking for alternatives to the words **phrase** or **term** to describe *"the three-particle paradigm"*. Is it correct to refer to this one phrase as a **nomenclature**? Or is nomenclature more for a collection of words encompassing a bigger body of knowledge?

If nomenclature is invalid, please provide alternatives.

The reason I'm looking for a word like this is that I want to explain why I chose these words, such as:

> Allow me to explain the nomenclature "the three-particle paradigm": First, there are three particles. Second, ...

Using **phrase** doesn't sound too good to me.

Comment: *Nomenclature* is properly the act of assigning names or the system of names thus assigned. Just one name is exactly that: a *name*. "Allow me to explain the name X"--nothing fancier is needed.

Comment: @StoneyB *Name* is bit plain. Come to think of it, I think *designation* may work.

Comment: Nah, designation seems weird too...

Comment: Why not leave out that part? 'Allow me to explain *the three_particle paradigm* ...' seems good enough. That said, I don't see why term is a bad choice here.

Comment: Why not *definition* or *defined term*?

Comment: Well, if you're actively trying to achieve pomposity, you'd better make it *triparticular*, too. "Paradigm" is already just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While *[nomenclature](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nomenclature)* has a sense (now obsolete) corresponding to “name”, its more usual meanings  “A set of names or terms” and “A set of rules used for forming the names or terms in a particular field of arts or sciences” don't apply to your need.  Instead consider synonyms of name, such as   *[appellation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appellation#Noun)* (“A name, title or designation”).   A little less formally, you might use *[moniker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/moniker#Noun)*.